# to make a link enable when clicked on another link

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("close1").click(function() {
            $(".close2").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
        });
    });
</script>

<li>
    <a href=""  class="close1">Close</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="" class="close"  class="close2" style="position:absolute;left:auto">Tile Vertical</a>
</li>
```

Here I have declared a link called `Close`. After clicking on the link close, I should get line vertical as enabled which is disabled. This code is not working. Are there any modifications?

Answer (score 5):

You're missing `.` to target element by class name:

```
$(".close1").click(function
// ^ here -----------------
```

Also you've defined class two times for your second button, you just need:

```
class="close close2"
```

instead of:

```
class="close" class="close2"
```

Comment: Also double declation of class in second anchor

Comment: i modified all the changes you said but it is not working

Comment: With your current code, we can only spot out above mistakes. Otherwise, you can help us by creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in order to let me and others understand better about why it's not working here

Answer (score 0):

you must not declare double class attribute for a single html element

```
<a href="" class="close"  class="close2" style="position:absolute;left:auto">Tile Vertical</a>
```

Comment: ok then only add class="close2" then on clicking on close then tile vertical should get disabled.

Comment: disabled or enabled!! your comment is in contrast with your question.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".close2" ).bind( "click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    } );
    $(".close1").click(function() {
        $( ".close2" ).unbind( "click");
    });
});
```